# How pass null from code behind with textboxes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two textboxes and a drop down.User has a option that he should select drop down and enter value in any one of the texbox .

My procedure accepts null values . only problem is how to pass tht from code behind tht the any text box value submitted it shud return the data.

Can any one help me on this .

Thanks 
Smartdev

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked `int.Parse` or `int.TryParse` Methods along with `nullbale` int

some thing similar would work

```
int? couldBeNullInt;
couldBeNullInt = int.Parse(someTextBox.Text);
```

if the value returned is null, pass null to your procedure otherwise pass the non null value

such as

```
if(couldBeNullInt.HasValue && couldBeNullInt.Value !=null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do something like this:

```
int? enteredValue = null;
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textNumberEntry.Text))
{
    int temp = 0;
    if(int.TryParse(textNumberEntry.Text, out temp))
       enteredValue = temp;
}

// Call proc with enteredValue, check enteredValue.HasValue first though!
```